# Time series of categorical data -- how to calculate percent of each category, over time spans?

Tags: r, time-series, categorical-data

I have a dataframe of time stamps which specify a categorical status. The status is valid until the next time stamp, at which time the category might change.

I'd like to be able to determine percentage of time spent in each category over regular time periods, like monthly, quarterly, or annually.

This seems like a common enough problem, but I've been unable to find an elegant solution or library to solve it.

For example, with the following sample dataframe:

```
            date    status
2016-02-20 09:11:00      a
2016-03-06 02:38:00      c
2016-03-10 15:20:00      b
2016-03-10 21:20:00      a
2016-03-11 11:51:00      b
2016-03-12 01:19:00      c
2016-03-22 14:39:00      c
2016-03-23 11:37:00      b
2016-03-25 17:38:00      c
2016-03-26 01:24:00      c
2016-03-26 12:40:00      a
2016-04-12 10:28:00      c
```

... I might want to report weekly from 3/1-3/7, 3/8-3/14, 3/15-3/21, the percent time in each week of 'a', 'b', and 'c' status.

I started brute force coding a solution to this (it's ugly...), when I decided maybe I should ask here whether there's a more elegant way to do it.

---

======== *Edited to add an inelegant brute-force solution below* ========

```
time_analysis <- function(df, starttime, endtime) {
  # - assumes sorted by date

  startindex <- sum(df$date <= starttime) # find the index of the entry which contains the start time
  endindex <- sum(df$date <= endtime) + 1 # find the index of the entry which contains the end time

  if ( (startindex == 0) || (endindex > nrow(df) ) ) {
    print("Date outside of available data")
    return(NULL)
  }

  df2 <- df[ startindex:endindex, ] # subset the dataframe to include the range, but still need to trim ends

  df2$date[1] <- starttime # trim to the start time
  df2$date[nrow(df2)] <- endtime # trim back the end time
  df2$status[nrow(df2)] <- df2$status[nrow(df2)-1] # status hasn't changed yet, so still the previous status

  duration <- diff(df2$date) # vector of the time within each segment, 1 fewer elements than the dataframe
  units(duration) <- 'days'
  duration <- as.numeric(duration) # need to convert to numeric, or else can't divide by total duration

  df2 <- df2[ -nrow(df2), ] # remove the last row, to make length same as the duration vector
  df2$duration <- duration # add the duration column

  total <- sum(df2$duration) # to allow calculations within the ddply
  return(ddply(df2[, c('status','duration')], 'status', function(x) { # calculate by each status category
    return( c(
      date = starttime,
      totaldays = round(sum(x$duration), 2),
      fraction = round(sum(x$duration) / total, 3)) )
  } ))
}
```

And below would be a sample use, that would split the reporting into roughly 2-week chunks. I hate the use manual date coding and using a loop in R, but am too inexperienced to know a better way.

```
times <- c("2016-03-01","2016-03-15","2016-04-01","2016-04-15","2016-05-01","2016-05-15")
result <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:(length(times) - 1)) {
  result <- rbind( result, time_analysis(d, times[i], times[i+1]) )
}
print(result, row.names = FALSE)
```

Yielding (other than some errors for dates out of range):

```
status       date totaldays fraction
     a 2016-03-01      5.71    0.409
     b 2016-03-01      0.81    0.058
     c 2016-03-01      7.43    0.532
     a 2016-03-15      5.47    0.322
     b 2016-03-15      2.25    0.132
     c 2016-03-15      9.28    0.546
```

=====
And after posting, found a much nicer way to generate the times:

```
times <- as.character( seq( as.Date("2016-03-01"), as.Date("2016-05-15"), by = '2 weeks' ) )
```

Comment: It would help if you give the desired output for your sample input so that answers can be verified. It seems like you should just be able to take the `diff()` of your date/time column and aggregate that with the corresponding status (ignoring the last status which you have no end time for). It's important to indicate how you are choosing your interval breaks and what you want to do for times that span those intervals.

Comment: Something like `do.call(rbind, tapply(df$status, months(df$date), function(x){prop.table(table(x)) * 100}))`, perhaps

Comment: @alistaire That will not work if the data set spans multiple years, since the same month in different years would be aggregated together. Could replace the `months()` call with `format()` to include both the year and the month, e.g. `format(df$date,'%Y-%m')`.

Comment: Sure. The question left the grouping vague, so you can insert whatever you like and it'll work. `cut` is a nice option, e.g. for weeks: `cut(df$date, 'week')`

Comment: I didn't make clear that a challenge is that, for example, the first two lines mean that from 2016-02-20 09:11 through 2016-03-06 02:38, the status is 'a', which means that if doing a "by month", then I should take into account that from 2016-03-01 00:00 through 2016-03-06 02:38, the status is 'a', after which it becomes 'c'. So, doing a simple grouping by month doesn't work because it'd miss the first ~5-6 days of March. I edited the original post with my 'brute force' inelegant solution, but had thought there just might be a 'use ### command form ### package' solution that I could learn of!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that combines the [`cut.POSIXt()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.POSIXt.html) S3 specific with a nested [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) aggregation.

```
## define data
library(data.table);
dt <- data.table(date=as.POSIXct(c('2016-02-20 09:11:00','2016-03-06 02:38:00','2016-03-10 15:20:00','2016-03-10 21:20:00','2016-03-11 11:51:00','2016-03-12 01:19:00','2016-03-22 14:39:00','2016-03-23 11:37:00','2016-03-25 17:38:00','2016-03-26 01:24:00','2016-03-26 12:40:00','2016-04-12 10:28:00')),status=c('a','c','b','a','b','c','c','b','c','c','a','c'));

## solution
dt[,{ n1 <- .N; .SD[,.(pct=.N/n1*100),.(status)]; },.(month=cut(df$date,'month'))];
##         month status pct
## 1: 2016-02-01      a 100
## 2: 2016-03-01      c  50
## 3: 2016-03-01      b  30
## 4: 2016-03-01      a  20
## 5: 2016-04-01      c 100
```